# Subquery with Linq to Sql

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have following LINQ statement. How do I change this so I get GroupIDs only in the subquery.
My syntax here is not working.

And also only distinct Users.

```
from u in Users 
join ug in UserGroups on u.UserID equals ug.UserID
where ug.GroupID == (from igr in UserGroups where igr.UserID == 1 select igr.GroupID)
select u
```

Answer (score 1):

I would break it into two separate queries for readability but here goes

```
var group = from igr in UserGroup
            where irg.UserID == 1
            select igr.GroupID;

var result = from u in Users 
              join ug in UserGroups on u.UserID equals ug.UersID
              into x
              where group.Contains( x.GroupID )
              select x;
```

As one query I believe it would work like this

```
var result = from u in Users 
              join ug in UserGroups on u.UserID equals ug.UersID
              into x
              where 
                (from igr in UserGroup
                 where irg.UserID == 1
                 select igr.GroupID).Contains( x.GroupID )
              select x;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how a did it in then end.

```
var query = (from u in _dbctx.Users
    join ug in _dbctx.UserGroups on u.UserID equals ug.UserID
    where _dbctx.UserGroups.Any(igr => igr.GroupID == ug.GroupID && igr.UserID == 1)
    select GetUser(u)).Distinct();
```

Comment: StackOverflow uses Markdown for formatting (see: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax). Things like `[code][/code]` don't work here.

Answer (score 0):

```
    from u in Users 
    join ug in UserGroups on u.UserID equals ug.UserID
    where ug.GroupID == (from igr in UserGroups where igr.UserID == 1 select  igr.GroupID).FirstOrDefault()
    select u
```

inner query must return exactly one value